# Help to prove that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx\ = \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(1+\alpha), \alpha \gt 0 $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to show that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx= \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(1+\alpha),\qquad\qquad\alpha \gt 0. $$

For $\alpha=1$, I showed it in the following way:
Let $x=\tan u$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac {\arctan x}{x(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx & =\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} u\cot u\,\mathrm du\\ & =\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}u\,\mathrm d(\log\sin u) \\ & =-\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin u\,\mathrm du\\ & =\frac {\pi}2\ln 2
\end{align*}
From the second line to the third line, I used the integration by parts, From the third line to the last line, I used the King's property.

But, I couldn't show it for any $\alpha$. Also, I don't know if it is true or not. Can anyone help me for the general case, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must improve your text.

Comment: What happened to $\alpha$ in the solution you posted?

Comment: @FrankW that's why I'm asking:) I didn't understand that solution, but I thought that it has some hint to the solution for my question

Comment: @Korostev The solution assumes $\alpha=1$ and enforces the substitution $u=\arctan x$. The reason why that won't work for your integral though is because you have an $\alpha$ in the integral. You can use Feynman's Trick and then partial fraction decomposition

Comment: Haven’t found the link yet, but I’m certain this question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @FrankW omg, we haven't learned Feynman's Trick in the university before. You opened my eyes to such a cool solution method. I solved the task, thank you!!!!

Comment: @Korostev Nice!

Comment: How did you prove it? I can not do. @Korostev

Comment: @BobDobbs Hey! just added the solution below

Comment: @Korostev x cancels! I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\arctan{(\alpha x)}}{x(1+x^{2})}dx$$

let $\alpha = 0$, then :

$$f(0)=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\arctan{(0)}}{x(1+x^{2})}dx=0$$

Now differentiate

\begin{align*}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha} & =\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\partial }{\partial \alpha}\frac{\arctan{(\alpha x)}}{x(1+x^{2})}\,\mathrm dx\\
 & =\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\mathrm dx}{(x^2\alpha^2+1)(1+x^{2})}\\
 & =\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\alpha^{2}}{(\alpha^{2}-1)(\alpha^{2}x^2+1)}-\frac{1}{(\alpha^{2}-1)(x^2+1)}\,\mathrm dx\\
 & =\frac{\alpha^{2}}{\alpha^{2}-1}\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\alpha^{2}x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx-\frac{1}{\alpha^{2}-1} \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align*}

Now calculate the 1st integral, using the substitution $u=x\alpha$ and $\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm du}{\alpha}$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\alpha^{2}x^2+1}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\mathrm du}{u^{2}+1}=\frac{\arctan u}{\alpha}=\frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{\alpha}.$$

And 2nd integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2+1}=\arctan x$$

Then we have:

\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{\alpha^{2}\arctan(x\alpha)}{\alpha(\alpha^{2}-1)}-\frac{\arctan x}{\alpha^{2}-1}\right]^{\infty}_{0} & 
=\left[\frac{\alpha\arctan(x\alpha)-\arctan x}{\alpha^{2}-1}\right]^{\infty}_{0}\\
 & =\frac{\pi\alpha-\pi}{2(\alpha^{2}-1)}\\
 & =\frac{\pi}{2(\alpha+1)}
\end{align*}

Integrating back to recover $f(\alpha)$ gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{\pi}{2(\alpha+1)}\qquad\implies\qquad f(\alpha)=\frac{\pi\ln(2\alpha+2)}{2}+C$$

When $\alpha=0$

$$f(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2+C=0\implies C=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$

Thus

$$f(\alpha)=\frac{\pi \ln(2\alpha+2)}{2}+C=\frac{\pi \ln(2\alpha+2)}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\frac{2\alpha+2}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(1+\alpha)$$

Comment: Please use ```\implies```, ```\arctan```,```\ln```. I have given you a few examples in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{arctan(\alpha x)}{x(x^2+1)}$, $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}i\frac{\log(1-i\alpha x)}{x(x^2+1)}$ and $f_2(x)=-\frac{1}{2}i\frac{\log(1+i\alpha x)}{x(x^2+1)}$. Then $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$.

Now, $I=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=I_1+I_2$ where $I_1=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_1(x)dx$ and $I_2=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_2(x)dx$.

Computation of $I_1$: Let $0<\epsilon<1<R$ and $C_1$ be the closed counter-clockwise contour on the upper half plane, starting form $-R$ to $-\epsilon$ on $x$-axis, to $+\epsilon$ along the semi-circle $|z|=\epsilon$, to $+R$ on $x$-axis and then back to $-R$ along the semi-circle $|z|=R$. Then the integral of $f_1(z)$ is defined on $C_1$. By $ML$-inequality, it is easy to show that the integral tends to zero on semi-circles when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ and $R\rightarrow\infty$. Then, by residue theorem,
$$I_1=\frac{1}{2}2\pi i \left(Res_{z=i}f_1(z)\right)=\frac{1}{2}2\pi i\frac{1}{2}i\frac{\ln(1+\alpha)}{(i)(2i)}=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(1+\alpha).$$

Computation of $I_2$: Let $0<\epsilon<1<R$ and $C_2$ be the closed counter-clockwise contour on the lower half plane, starting form $+R$ to $+\epsilon$ on $x$-axis, to $-\epsilon$ along the semi-circle $|z|=\epsilon$, to $-R$ on $x$-axis and then back to $+R$ along the semi-circle $|z|=R$. Then the integral of $f_2(z)$ is defined on $C_2$. By $ML$-inequality, it is easy to show that the integral tends to zero on semi-circles when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ and $R\rightarrow\infty$. Then, by residue theorem,
$$I_2=-\frac{1}{2}2\pi i \left(Res_{z=-i}f_2(z)\right)=-\frac{1}{2}2\pi i(-\frac{1}{2}i\frac{\ln(1+\alpha)}{(-i)(-2i)})=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(1+\alpha).$$
Hence, $I=I_1+I_2=2I_1=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(1+\alpha).$